# Concept of differentiation for rectilinear motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

> From point $A$ located on a highway one has to get by car as soon as possible to point $B$ located in the field at a distance $l$ from the highway. It is known that the car moves on the filed $n$ times slower than on highway. At what distance from the point $D$ (point on highway from where $DB\perp AD$ at $D$) one must turn off the highway?

My tries:

Velocity of car on highway$=v\implies\text{ Velocity of car on field}=\dfrac{v}{n}$

Let $CD=x$ and $AD=b\implies T=t_{AC}+t_{CB}=\dfrac{b-x}{v}+\dfrac{\sqrt{l^2+x^2}}{(v/n)}$

Now when I  differentiated it w.r.t. time and equated to $0$ I got nothing special but when I differentiated it w.r.t. $x$ and equated to $0$ I got my answer, why is so happening?

What does differentiating w.r.t. time and $x$ signifies, whats the intuition behind both differentiation?

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean by "differentiating w.r.t. time" in context. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @probably_someone w.r.t.=with respect to.

Comment: Here is what I mean: Can you post exactly what you did when you differentiated with respect to time?

Comment: @probably_someone Ok I got to know that differentiating wrt time is meaningless (as $\dfrac{dT}{dt}=1$), but what physical quantity came out when time is differentiated wrt $x$?

Comment: @probably_someone oh forgot to mention, point from where we turned before $D$ towards $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you differentiate time with respect to $x$, you are answering the question: *How much more time does it take to travel from point $A$ to point $B$ if I turn a little bit earlier, assuming I'm turning at point $x$ already?*

Comment: can it be elaborated, please.

Comment: @mathlover In what way? What is your specific issue with it?

Comment: how can be independent quantity-time be differentiated wrt constant $x$.

Comment: @mathlover Time is not an independent quantity here. It is dependent on $x$, which _is_ an independent quantity in this context, and is not constant - indeed, it's the only part of the problem that we're varying.

Comment: so $\frac{dT}{dx}=$? is what you wrote in answer?

Comment: @mathlover Yes.